# Tor won't connect

Tags: help

When I hit connect it gives me this:

```
10/29/2015 1:56:06 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/29/2015 1:56:07 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/29/2015 1:56:14 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
10/29/2015 1:56:14 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
10/29/2015 1:56:56 AM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
10/29/2015 1:56:57 AM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
10/29/2015 1:56:57 AM.000 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
10/29/2015 1:56:57 AM.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
10/29/2015 1:57:14 AM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 178.209.52.110:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
10/29/2015 2:05:53 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/29/2015 2:05:53 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/29/2015 2:05:53 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```